# Iterative method of converting a decimal number to binary

Tags: binary, iteration

Recursive method

```
public void intToBinary(int n)
 if(n==0)
  return 0;
 else 
  System.out.print(n%2)
  return intToBinary(n/2)
```

Im trying to do the same thing using the iterative method, getting an int as a parameter and returning an int as well. Is there a way to do it without having to use arrays? Im not sure about what the loop should do. Any help is appreciated. :)

Comment: You can still just print the bits out, since you aren't returning anything meaningful. Why does your method return int, since it always returns zero? Also, you are printing the bits in reverse order from least significant to most significant.

Comment: Thanks for pointing those issues out. I forgot about the reverse order. Any ideas on a iterative method.

Comment: You should remove the `0` from `return 0` and the final `return` since your method is now declared as returning `void`. Just do `intToBinary(n/2)` as the last step, without the return. Also, you'll have to add braces in the proper places if you want it to compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an iterative version of the same method:

```
public void intToBinary(int n) {
    while (n != 0) {
        System.out.print(n % 2);
        n = n / 2;
    }
}
```